# Does the Prouhet-Thue-Morse sequence eventually contain its bitwise boolean complement in whole?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, bit-strings

My intuition says that it does not, but I am struggling to prove it. It definitely contains any finite consecutive subsequence ("substring") of the latter, by its construction. I also suspect that, even under best alignment, the alignment breaks at the $2^n$th term for some nonnegative integer $n$. But I do not have a strong enough grasp of the sequence in orded to prove the result.

Comment: Everything is known about this infinite word or can be easily deduced from what is already known. So if you explain what is 
"bitwise boolean complement in whole", you will probably get an answer.

Comment: I mean "contain the whole of the bitwise boolean complement sequence". So, if (T_n) is the PTM sequence and (t_n) is the bitwise boolean complement (so that t_i = 1 - T_i for all i), then there exists an M such that T_(M+j) = t_j for all j.

Comment: $M=2?{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @markvs the sequence starts $0,1,1,0,1$. $M≠2$.

Answer (score 2):

The Thue Morse Sequence obey the recurrence relation :
$$\begin{cases} t_0 = 0\\
t_{2n} = t_n\\
t_{2n+1} = 1-t_{n}\end{cases}$$

Suppose there exist a subsequence equal to the bitwise boolean complement Thue Morse sequence.
If the subsequence start at the $k$-st term, we would have the additional requirement :
$$t_n = 1 - t_{n-k}$$
And so, we should have
$$t_{2n} = 1 - t_{2n-k}$$
It fails when $n = 2n-k$ i.e. $n = k$, so the subsequence starting at $k$ will be no longer than $k$

Comment: You have a mistake; the second equation should be $t_{2n}=1-t_{2(n-k)}$, so you need to do something else to get a contradiction.

Comment: No, you just replace $n$ by $2n$

Comment: I see now, +1. I think it would be simpler to just say starting from $t_n=1-t_{n-k}$, that we get a contradiction if $n=2(n-k)$, i.e. when $n=2k$. No need for second equation.